# Android: contact popup opens when I tap a number in the browser - want to disable

Tags: android, sencha-touch, motorola

I have an app written in HTML 5 using the sencha touch 2 library. 
I am using the motorola xyboard 8.2" with android honeycomb to access the site. 
Some of my dropdown menus and popups contain numbers. 
When I touch the number, an android popup opens to suggest that I add the number to my contacts. 
The numbers are not for contacts, and I would like to disable this completely so I can tap the numbers and they do not trigger anything.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I have the same problem.. please help !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```